# Incorporating fuzzy search in a matcher object

Tags: c, cython, spacy, matcher

My task is querying medical texts for institute names using a rule as below:

```
[{'ENT_TYPE': 'institute_name'}, {'TEXT': 'Hospital'}]
```

The rule will only idenify a match if both terms are included therein. Thus, it will accept "Mount Sinai Hospital", but not "Mount Sinai".  I've tried [spaczz](https://pypi.org/project/spaczz/) that wraps spaCy and works great for single term or phrase. However neither spaCy not spaczz allow for a fuzzy multi-words rule with more than one typo as in "Moung Sinai Mospital."

Therefore, I'm trying to re-write the [Matcher object](https://spacy.io/api/matcher) by incorporating a fuzzy similarity algorithm such as [RapidFuzz](https://github.com/maxbachmann/rapidfuzz) but I'm having some difficulty with its Cython component.

The Matcher's Class [**call** method](https://spacy.io/api/matcher#call) finds all token sequences matching the supplied patterns on doclike, the document to match over or a Span (Type: Doc/Span), returning
a list of (match_id, start, end) tuples, describing the matches:

```
matches = find_matches (&self.patterns[0], self.patterns.size(), doclike, length,
                            extensions=self._extensions, predicates=self._extra_predicates)
    for i, (key, start, end) in enumerate(matches):
        on_match = self._callbacks.get(key, None)
        if on_match is not None:
            on_ma
    return matches
```

find_matches is a cython class that returns the matches in a doc, with a compiled array of patterns as a list of (id, start, end) tuples and has main loop that seems to match the doc against the pre-defined patterns:

```
# Main loop
cdef int nr_predicate = len(predicates)
for i in range(length):
        for j in range(n):
                  states.push_back(PatternStateC(patterns[j], i, 0))
            transition_states(states, matches, predicate_cache,
                   doclike[i], extra_attr_values, predicates)
        extra_attr_values += nr_extra_attr
        predicate_cache += len(predicates)
```

Can you help me locate the actual matching operation (pattern against string) in the python/C-level objects as attributes? I hope to be able to extend this operation with the fuzzy matching algorithm. You can find the code for the Matcher class, the *call* method and the find_matches class [here](https://github.com/explosion/spaCy/blob/master/spacy/matcher/matcher.pyx).

You can follow a more pythonic effort to achieve this goal by spaczz [here](https://github.com/gandersen101/spaczz/issues/24).

Comment: Are you specifically interested in a Cython solution or a Python one can do? If the latter is an option, please post a reproducible example, against which it can be tested. As well, show the threshold of what should be found and not (positive and negative examples).

Answer (score 0):

I think the easiest way would be to add an additional predicate type called something like `FUZZY`. Look at how the regex, set, and comparison predicates are defined and do something similar for `FUZZY` with your custom code to match on strings with small edit differences:

https://github.com/explosion/spaCy/blob/master/spacy/matcher/matcher.pyx#L687-L781

The predicate classes are standard python classes, no cython required. You'll also need to add the predicate to the schema in `spacy/matcher/_schemas.py`.

Remember that like the rest of the `Matcher` predicates, it matches over tokens, so your definition of fuzziness will have to be at the token level.